# Test integration for cache REST API

Tags: java, rest, caching, junit

I have implemented a **REST service** with **cache mechanism** where the **cache** is **valid** for 5 minutes as follows:

```
public Response findNberofPointsByUserIdCache(Long userId, Long exerciseId) {
    Integer nberPoints=exerciseDao.calculateNberOfPoints(userId,exerciseId);
    CacheControl cc = new CacheControl();
    cc.setMaxAge(300);// for 5 minutes
    cc.setPrivate(true);

    ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok(nberPoints);
    builder.cacheControl(cc);
    return builder.build();

}
```

I would like to test it with `@Test` Junit. How can I do it?

Comment: What is it you want to test? That the cache lifetime is exactly 5 minutes? Or the entire functonality itself?

Comment: I want to test the cache lifetime is 5 minutes for the rest i tested it.

Comment: Is is `javax.ws.rs.core.CacheControl` ? So this are the HTTP response headers for cache control in the **client**. You may test the response header in your browser, if the response header are included. Anyway, the client will decide, if request data again or not ( the client may ignore cache headers completely).
Maybe this can help you to trace on the server: http://half-wit4u.blogspot.com.es/2012/11/cache-control-using-restfull-web-service.html

Comment: Please refer to the SO link that contains an answer to a similar question. The RestAssured library can be found here.

I have not used this - but I guess it should be easy to integrate with JUnit.